# Searching for NULL values in feature class table

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute, null

I am looking for a way which I can search whole my feature class in ArcMap to find if has any `NULL` values on it.
I know how can I do this with `"Select By Attribute"`, but I am looking for a faster way to do this, like with a Python script.

Comment: If you're after a python script what have you got so far? A cursor (arcpy.da) will let you loop through features looking for row[index] == None to find Null values, also look at ListFields https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001t000000

Comment: I just start to learn python by myself I am good with ArcMap software

Comment: There's little chance a Python script will  improve on the performance of a tool like Select By Attribute. Both would be improved by creation of indexes, one per column to be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

If you're after a raw count of null values in any field:

```
sum(sum(v is None for v in values) for values in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('some_layer', '*'))
```

If you want to know specifically which rows/fields contain them:

```
count_nulls = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('some_layer', '*') as cursor:
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        null_fields = [name for name, value in
                       zip(cursor.fields, row) if value is None]
        if null_fields:
            print 'found nulls in row {}: {}'.format(
                i + 1, ', '.join(null_fields))
            count_nulls += len(null_fields)

print '{} total null values'.format(count_nulls)
```

Comment: I like the condensing to a single row but it's a bit hard for beginners to understand this type of expression. +1 anyway for getting the sum of nulls for a row, that's a great idea.

Comment: That's fair.  Although they did say they were after speed ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I quickly put together:

```
import os, sys, arcpy
InFC = sys.argv[1]

Desc       = arcpy.Describe(InFC) # describe the feature class properties
OidName    = Desc.OIDFieldName    # find out what the OID field is called
AllFields  = [Fld.name for Fld in arcpy.ListFields(InFC)] # get a list of field names
FieldRange = range(len(AllFields)) # make a range (a list witn [0,1,2..n] to iterate 
OidIndex   = AllFields.index(OidName) # the index of the row OID field

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFC) as SCur:
    # loop for each row
    for SRow in SCur:
        # loop for each field
        for Idx in FieldRange:
            if SRow[Idx] == None:
                # if this field, by index, is null issue a warning
                arcpy.AddWarning('Row {} has a null value in {}'.format(SRow[OidIndex],AllFields[Idx]))
```

Start with interrogating the input feature class to get some properties, in this case the [name of the OID field](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_properties/03q300000050000000/) and the names of all the fields ([ListFields](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001t000000) returns *field* objects, but we just want the names), I'm using a condensed form with iterates the fields an returns a list of field names in a single row which can be a little difficult to understand.

Now open an [arcpy.da.SearchCursor](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) on the feature class, by default it will have all fields then iterate the rows and loop by the indices in the range looking for Null (`None`) values and issue a warning with the rows OID and the field name that is blank.

To use this script have a read of [adding a python script to a toolbox](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000001r000000), this tool has only one parameter of type `FeatureClass`.

From here you could replace the [AddWarning](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000039000000) with [writing to a file](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) but because you're a beginner I wanted to keep this fairly simple.

Comment: If there are more than 10k-20k features in a feature class, it's probably worth the performance hit to build an index before doing the query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the da.SearchCursor to check all fields ("*") and stop when the first row with a null value is found:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\features' #Change

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"*") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if None in row:
            print('I found a None')
            break
```